# how to set a variable to multiple values with awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file similar to the following :

```
x 0
1 x
1 1
```

and I am essentially trying to see if both fields are equal to one another or not for every row. But the problem is that this file contains `x` which can either hold the value of `0` or `1` -- but I am not sure how to set this in `awk`

I tried working with the following code that did not work, it only works if `x` is set to either `0` or `1`, not both.

```
y=$(seq 1 2)
awk -v x="$y" '{ if ($1==$2) print "good" }' file
```

Please advise or let me know if any clarification is necessary, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a variable to multiple values in any ordinary programming language that I know of, but you may most certainly loop over a set of values with a variable.

Construct a shell loop around the `awk` code that runs for each value of `x`:

```
for x in 0 1; do
    printf 'Running with x=%d\n' "$x"
    awk -v x="$x" \
        '$1 == "x" { $1 = x }
         $2 == "x" { $2 = x }
         $1 == $2  { printf("match on line %d: %d == %d\n", NR, $1, $2) }' file.in
done
```

The `awk` code tests the two columns for the character `x` and (if true) sets it to the current value of the `awk` variable `x` (which is set on the command line).

If the columns later are the same, some output is produced.

With the given data, this produces the output

```
Running with x=0
match on line 1: 0 == 0
match on line 3: 1 == 1
Running with x=1
match on line 2: 1 == 1
match on line 3: 1 == 1
```

---

Alternatively, move the loop into `awk` (which which is much more efficient as the shell does not need to start `awk` more than once):

```
awk -v x="$x" \
        '{ for (x=0; x<=1; ++x) {
               printf("x is %d\n", x);
               if ($1 == "x") { a = x } else { a = $1 }
               if ($2 == "x") { b = x } else { b = $2 }
               if (a == b) { printf("match on line %d: %d == %d\n", NR, a, b) }
           }
          }' file.in
```

Output:

```
x is 0
match on line 1: 0 == 0
x is 1
x is 0
x is 1
match on line 2: 1 == 1
x is 0
match on line 3: 1 == 1
x is 1
match on line 3: 1 == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A scalar variable in awk can only hold a single variable. You'll have to do something like this:

```
if (
    ($1 == "x" && ($2 == 0 || $2 == 1)) ||
    ($2 == "x" && ($1 == 0 || $1 == 1)) ||
    $1 == $2
) print "good"
```